# jQuery parentsUntil() id is found

Tags: jquery, parent

Is there a way to make [parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) stop just after the first element with an id? For example I would like `li ul div#id-found` to be returned when I click on the li.

```
<div id="id-found">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's an example js fiddle (that's slightly more advanced than this example): http://jsfiddle.net/T9gBu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best way to achieve what you want:

```
var $t = $(this), $p = $t.parentsUntil('[id]') 
$p = $t.add($t.closest('*[id]').add($p));
```

now `$p` has an upwards trail of elements you can map and join etc.

Here is the modified fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/awnvowan/

There were also couple of problems with your fiddle. If I understand correctly what you need, it is most efficient to handle string building directly in the mapper:

```
var selector = 
    $p.map(function() { 
        var $t = $(this), 
            id = $t.attr('id'),
            tag = $t.prop("tagName"),
            cls = $t.attr("class"); 
        if (cls) {
            cls = "." + $.trim(cls).replace(/\s/gi, ".");
        } else 
            cls = '';

        return tag + (id ? '#'+id : '') + cls;
    }).get().reverse().join(" ");
```

*Update* this answer has been updated based on jfaron comment.

Comment: This works! The only other thing I need is to include the id with the div (as this method only returns the tag and not its id) so I'm experimenting with that now. If you know how to do that too that would be very helpful. :)

Comment: There was a mistake, you need to use 'closest' to include the parent with id. I updated my answer to reflect it and improved the code a little.

Comment: Looks like it's not including the element that's been clicked, but you've gotten this close enough for me to figure it out. Thanks man!

Comment: Tx! I improved the selector builder a little bit, now it works everywhere on example document. Adding the actual clicked element is trivial, just do var $p = $(this).add($p) to have it all.

Comment: Excellent. I wish I could give you more than one vote. ;) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: classNames isn't set? How did no one report that?  should be cls.. `cls = "." + $.trim(cls).replace(/\s/gi, ".");`   I updated the fiddle to have this updated, along with the actual class of what was clicked, as per above. http://jsfiddle.net/pebfn/3/

Comment: @jfaron Thank you! We have no QA here, lol. I updated my answer and improved the fiddle a little (including yours) - to walk up to any element, not just div, and to avoid multiple vars.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two elements with the same ID on the same page. That is a basic rule of HTML. Once the ancestors of your element have unique IDs you can use .closest() to select the ID that you want.